# Returning view from jQuery AJAX get operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an asynchronous jQuery get to an MVC Action to return a view. For some reason, although it accesses the action, it does not render the view.

This is the jQuery:

```
function showArchive(url) {
    var moreRecentThanDate = $("#chooseDate").val();

    $.get(url, { moreRecentThan: moreRecentThanDate });
}
```

and this is the action :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowArchive(DateTime moreRecentThan)
    {
        List<NewIndexViewModel> model = Service.GetArchives(moreRecentThan);
        ViewBag.IsArchive = true;

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

PS:  I call this jQuery from an ad-hoc modal popup;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach the result in somewhere using a syntax like that:

```
$.get(url, { moreRecentThan: moreRecentThanDate }).done(function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
)};
```

Comment: Same problem like @Scotty.NET's answer: I would like to refresh the page somehow, if it is possible (this may sound really stupid, beeing an AJAX GET, I know).

Comment: for refresh you can use pure Javascript `location.reload();` if it makes sense to you

Comment: Thanks, I just forget I could set the location.href property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, check the jQuery documentation, [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), the second last example is what you want, I believe..

```
$.get(url, { moreRecentThan: moreRecentThanDate })
.done(function(data) {
  $('#myElem').append(data);
  // or $('#myElem').html(data);
});
```

Comment: what I need is to load the above mentioned view, a refresh, not just to append the result to an element in the view. It worked just fine through POST, but I received a requirement to use GET.

Comment: You don't need to do a **refresh**, or `reload()` if you don't want to, just append or substitute the html into an existing target element.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Part

```
$.get( url, { moreRecentThan: moreRecentThanDate }, function(data) {
```

// callback or response
        $('#details_Div').replaceWith(data);

```
});
```

where the user controller has an action named details that does:

```
public ActionResult Details( int id )
{
  //create a model

    return PartialView( "UserDetails", model );
}
```

`PartialView` is important here.

This is assuming that your partial view is a container with the id detailsDiv so that you just replace the entire thing with the contents of the result of the call.

UserDetails partial view 
http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-and-ajax-real-world-example/

```
<div id="details_Div">
    <HTML will be replaced once the ajax is completed>
</div>
```